# How to send json message via sockets with SSL

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sockets, ssl

Ok so I have created a C# application that sends a raw json formatted message using sockets. Then it listens for a response and then prints the response to a box. This code works, however I now need to add SSL support and I am not sure where to even start. I want to keep the basic logic as close to this as possible, I just need everything to be SSL encrypted... can you guys give me some pointers or thoughts on how best to approach this? I see the sslstream class but I am not quite sure how to integrate that into my existing code.

Here is my code:

```
private void test_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
      clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 7777);

      string get_menu_request = "{\"request\": \"get_stuff\"}";
      NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
      byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(get_stuff_request);
      serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
      serverStream.Flush();

      byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
      serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
      string _returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);

      response_text_box.AppendText(_returndata);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noted .Net has the SSLStream Class and on the MSDN page there are examples toward the bottom. This has also been covered in other places so I will just link to an example. The "SSL Sample" link gives a solid run through of how you build the socket and setup both the client and the server. Keep in mind SSL is certificate based so you will have to create a valid cert and tie that to the your stream.

[MSDN SSL Stream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

[SslStream Sample](http://leastprivilege.com/2005/02/28/sslstream-sample/)